# Warehouse and truck loading problem

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

I was driving by a warehouse that had a number of garage doors with trucks parked outside. This question came to mind, if you have one person at each dock loading the truck, it's easy to find out who is the most efficient at packing the trucks by looking at the number of items packed in a period of time. But if you increase the number of people loading each truck, how can you figure out the individual contribution, so that you can rank the workers?

Comment: It's a bit of an oversimplification to assume that a person is a machine that loads $n$ items onto a truck per hour, but even with that assumption, you would have to shuffle the work assignments so you have different people working together on different days. If you always have the same group working together you can assess the group's performance but not individual performance.

Answer (score 0):

Hint  for less people we dont need calculus simple algebra would do. Now hy ohservation we can see which group of workers have loaded the truck maximum (assuming all trucks have same capacities). So now for eg if 10 kg is loaded by two people in 2 hrs then work done in  1 hr =$1/10$ so if person A does x work so in 1 hr $1/x$ then B does $1/(10-x)$ ij 1 hr. so we get a equation  $1/x+1/(10-x)=1/10$ solving you get x then you get $y=10-x$. If more than two people are there then accordingly you need more conditions like total time if both work together,indivdual time of work, rate of filling of truck ie rate of filling of volume of container=$dV/dt$ etc.